# C project will not compile with Clang - Undefined symbols for arch

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, clang

I have been writing a C project, which I usually compile and run using GCC. However, I am now trying to work on this project on my M2 Macbook, which replaces GCC with Clang.

When using GCC, I am keeping all of the headers in a single `include/` directory. The project structure is as follows:

```
bin/                // Binary output location
docs/
include/            // Header files are here
input/
makefile
obj/                // Generated object .o files here
src/                // Actual source code, .c files
tesh.sh
```

My makefile is as follows:

```
# Compiler Makefile
# Author: John L. Carveth <jlcarveth@gmail.com>
SRC_DIR := src# Source Code Location
OBJ_DIR := obj# Object Output Location
BIN_DIR := bin# Binary Output location
DOC_DIR := docs# Document location
OUT_DIR := out# Testing output location
CC := gcc
# Output file named ZeroCompiler
TARGET := $(BIN_DIR)/ZeroCompiler
# Include directory
IDIR := include
# All source files to compile
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
# Object files linked to the .c files
OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
# All Document files to be rendered (all files w/ .md extension)
DOC := $(wildcard $(DOC_DIR)/*.md)

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS := -Wall -D DEBUG -g
CPPFLAGS := -I$(IDIR) -MMD -MP
LDFLAGS := -Llib
LDLIBS := -lm

# PHONY targets so they can still be executed
.PHONY: all clean docs

all : $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ) | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @$(RM) -rv $(TARGET) $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR) $(DOC_DIR)/out $(OUT_DIR)
docs: 
    mkdir -p $(DOC_DIR)/out
    mdtodoc $(DOC) --dest "docs/out" --layout "page" --theme "github" --highlight-style "atom-one-light"

test:
    ./test.sh

-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)
```

My makefile would generate the necessary object files, link them, and generates a working binary output when I used GCC. On my Macbook however, I am getting the following error when running `make`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_arithmeticExpression", referenced from:
    _forStatement in Parser.o
[...]
```

In this case, `arithmeticExpression` is a function that who's prototype is defined within one of the header files within 'includes/'.

Now obviously it seems that I am lacking some understanding of the entire compilation process. How can I ensure I am properly linking the `includes/` directory when compiling my application?

Comment: This seems to be a mixed architecture problem, nothing to do with include files. Have you tried `make clean` before building? Make sure you don't have any object files from another system when you start.

Comment: Functions are not defined in header files. You need to include to the project the `.c` file containing the definition of this function.

Comment: @0___________ Defining functions in C lang headers was what I was taught in my post secondary education. Do you have a source to support the claim that function definitions do not belong in headers?

Comment: You're going to need to forget a lot of what you learned in school because in many, if not most C courses you don't learn C, you learn your teacher's wild, wacky interpretation of C. Don't *define* your functions in the headers. *Declare* them, but only if they're used outside the scope of the file they're defined in.

Comment: @JLCarveth header files should contain only ***function prototypes*** not definitions (with some exceptions - for example they may contain definitions of static inline functions - but I believe it is far beyond the scope of this function).

Comment: I think it's just a terminology error.  it can be confusing but the _declaration_ of a function is the prototype without the implementation: you put this in the header file.  The _definition_ of a function is its implementation.  You put that into a source file (of course, for inline functions or templates the definition has to go into the header as well).

Comment: @MadScientist what templates?

Comment: Right, well, templates are only relevant for C++ code not C code.

Comment: @MadScientist no one is using templates so I am unsure why you'd mention that...

Comment: Because they are things that have to go into header files and which people often incorrectly put into source files, and I don't want to say "implementations go into source files" without mentioning the exceptions to that rule, else people come back and say "what about this or that?"